# ios fwrite function EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, fwrite

I try to use fwrite (C function) in iPhone app.

For custom reasons, I don't want to use **writeToFile** but **fwrite** C function.

I wrote this code in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function :

```
  FILE *p = NULL;
  NSString *file= [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Hello.txt"];
  char buffer[80] = "Hello World";
  p = fopen([file UTF8string], "w");
  if (p!=NULL) {
      fwrite(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, p);
      fclose(p);
  }
```

But I get error **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** in fwrite function.

Any help ?

Comment: Check return value of `fopen()`: returns `NULL` on failure to open file.

Comment: I check it, and it's different from NULL. I edit my post with code.

Comment: this question might be stupid but... why don't you use the standard `NSFileManager` or use the `-writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` or `-writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:` with an `NSString` object...? there is no guarantee you have an access to write a file into the sandbox with the `fwrite()` function on iPhone...

Comment: The code is wrong, as the `if` would always be false.

Comment: To hmjd Code is not wrong, updated in first post
To holex As I told to George Aguirre in his answer, I would like to use fwrite. But I keep get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on this simple code !

Comment: i can not reproduce your issue with your code.. Can you explain: what  was problem and which way was fixed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are writing in the wrong place. It is far simpler to use the functions provided in the NSString class, which allow you to write to a file. Get to the /Documents folder of your app's sandbox (your app's sandbox is the only place you are allowed to write files freely)

```
NSString *stringToWrite =  @"TESTING";
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/filename.txt"];
[stringToWrite writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I think this is the simplest approach. You could to the same with fwrite, you would just need to convert the path to a cstring using cstringUsingEncoding, like this:

```
NSString *stringToWrite =  @"TESTING";
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/filename.txt"];
char *pathc =  [path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
char *stringToWritec = [stringToWrite cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

NOTE: I'm almost sure that apple uses UTF8 encoding for it's file names. If not, try NSASCIIStringEncoding and NSISOLatin1StringEncoding.

Comment: I use now NSHomeDirectory (code edited), I see the Hello.txt file created but empty, and still EXC_BAD_ACCESS at fwrite function.

Comment: I really want to use C function "fwrite", is it possible ?

Comment: Yes of course, the only problem is, fwrite receives a c-string, not an NSstring. So, after calculating the path you need to convert the string to a c-string. I'll add the code to my answer.

Comment: UTF8string method of NSString returns C string (char *) but I still get error

Comment: Try with ASCII encoding. To debug, you can use fprint for cstrings and NSLog for NSStrings.

Comment: You should actually use `fileSystemRepresentation` and not `cStringUsingEncoding`. Using the former provides a correctly encoded c-string for the given filesystem.